# How to design hierarchical content of large volume

Tags: information-architecture, content

I am working on a large intranet site, and there is lots of hierarchical content. I am having some trouble in balancing between the depth and breadth of the whole content. What do I do, can someone suggest something?

Comment: I firstly suggest that you give some insight as to what your product is and what you're trying to do. Also if possible, show us some work that you've done so far.

Comment: Always a good idea to try to put yourself into the shoes of your users. What are they trying to do when viewing this content? That'll help determine what sort of views make sense under specific workflows.

Answer (score 1):

A few recommendations:

**Ask users what they want and understand their priorities**

Can you identify target users of the intranet site and contact them to ask about the tasks they need to be able to complete on the intranet?  Also ask them to identify for you the highest priority tasks that they need to complete, and rank them if possible. After gathering input from a few target users you should have some empirical evidence to guide you as to how you should prioritize tasks that the IA needs to support.

**Identify early whether Search needs to be part of the experience**

You don’t mention if there is a need for search and/or filtering as part of the intranet experience, but if it is a large amount of content you may need to define a good scheme to allow users to find content they need.

Look for good examples of sites with comparable information scale and complexity.  In contrast with the past, corporate intranets must now serve user populations that have high expectations for usability. As such, it is worth it to look carefully at successful online consumer experiences – such as large-scale e-commerce sites - that enable consumers to easily and quickly search and find products from a very large collection of content.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an information architecture question. General recommendation (lacking references there) is to maximize the user's ability to find their way to the content over the time it would take them to get there. For instance, it's better to have more layers of information but have clear labels and navigation, than to try to make it "faster to get to" but it is a confusing organization.